# use the path separator to refer to an item

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I want do using rust diesel filter method to add a filter condition like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use crate::schema::dict::id;
mod schema;
mod models;

fn main() {
    use crate::diesel::prelude::*;
    use crate::schema::dict;
    let query = dict.filter(id.gt(0));
}
```

and this is the dict table scheme define:

```
table! {
dict (id) {
    word -> Varchar,
    phonetic -> Varchar,
    definition -> Varchar,
    translation -> Varchar,
    pos -> Varchar,
    collins -> Nullable<Int4>,
    oxford -> Nullable<Int4>,
    tag -> Varchar,
    bnc -> Int4,
    frq -> Int4,
    exchange -> Varchar,
    detail -> Varchar,
    audio -> Varchar,
    id -> Int8,
  }
}
```

this is the model define:

```
use rocket::serde::Serialize;
use rocket::serde::Deserialize;
use crate::schema::dict;

#[derive(Insertable, Serialize, Queryable, Deserialize,Default)]
#[table_name = "dict"]
pub struct QueryEdict {
    pub id: i64,
    pub word: String,
    pub phonetic: String,
    pub definition: String,
    pub translation: String,
    pub pos: String,
    pub collins: Option<i32>,
    pub oxford: Option<i32>,
    pub tag: String,
    pub bnc: i32,
    pub frq: i32,
    pub exchange: String,
    pub detail: String,
    pub audio: String,
}
```

show error when compile the rust code:

```
   Compiling rust-learn v0.1.0 (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/rust-learn)
error[E0423]: expected value, found module `dict`
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     let query = dict.filter(id.gt(0));
   |                 ^^^^-------
   |                 |
   |                 help: use the path separator to refer to an item: `dict::filter`
   |
note: unit struct `crate::models::dict::dsl::dict` exists but is inaccessible
  --> src/schema.rs:1:1
   |
1  | / table! {
2  | |     dict (id) {
3  | |         word -> Varchar,
4  | |         phonetic -> Varchar,
...  |
17 | |     }
18 | | }
   | |_^ not accessible
   = note: this error originates in the macro `__diesel_table_impl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0423`.
error: could not compile `rust-learn` due to previous error
```

why could not using the diesel filter? what should I do to fix it? This is the `Cargo.toml` define:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
serde_derive = "1.0"
# database
diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres"] }
```

this is the system info:

- rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
- diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono"] }
- Operation System: macOS Monterey 12.3
- Databse: PostgreSQL 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message clearly show the problem:

```
   Compiling rust-learn v0.1.0 (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/rust-learn)
error[E0423]: expected value, found module `dict`
  --> src/main.rs:11:17
   |
11 |     let query = dict.filter(id.gt(0));
   |                 ^^^^-------
   |                 |
   |                 help: use the path separator to refer to an item: `dict::filter`
   |
note: unit struct `crate::models::dict::dsl::dict` exists but is inaccessible
  --> src/schema.rs:1:1
   |
1  | / table! {
2  | |     dict (id) {
3  | |         word -> Varchar,
4  | |         phonetic -> Varchar,
...  |
17 | |     }
18 | | }
   | |_^ not accessible
   = note: this error originates in the macro `__diesel_table_impl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0423`.
error: could not compile `rust-learn` due to previous error
```

It states that there is no value `dict` in scope, only a module with that name. A module is not valid in value position. Additionally it gives you a hint how to fix that:

```
note: unit struct `crate::models::dict::dsl::dict` exists but is inaccessible
```

This gives you the hint that there is a unit struct with the same name available, but it is not imported. Importing this type does fix your problem.

To give a bit more context: Unit structs are type definitions + value in one. So for

```rust
struct UnitStruct;
```

the identifier `UnitStruct` can be used in value and in type position. Diesel uses unit structs as identifier for table and column names. Checkout the ["Schema in depth" guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/schema-in-depth.html) for details.