# expected struct `Gt`, found struct `And` when write diesel filter with multi line

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I want to append the filter in rust diesel `diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono"] }` and tried to do like this(if this works, I could add the conditional query for the diesel query):

```
pub fn interview_query<T>(request: &Json<InterviewRequest>) -> PaginationResponse<Vec<Interview>> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::interview::dsl::*;
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let mut query = interview.filter(id.gt(0));
    query = query.filter(id.gt(0));
}
```

when I compile the code, shows that:

```
20 |     query = query.filter(id.gt(0));
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Gt`, found struct `And`
```

is it possible to append filter in rust diesel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use the path separator to refer to an item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526033/use-the-path-separator-to-refer-to-an-item)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice if you do not get a answer directly.

Comment: @weiznich To a casual reading, this does not appear to be the same question as that.

Comment: @spark Do you have a link to the documentation for the `interview.filter` method (also, is `interview` a typo?), and the other `filter` method? And not to answer in a comment, but does it solve your problem if you don't make `query` `mut` but instead reassign the result to a new variable with another `let query = ...`?

Comment: I want to append the query conditional with the exists query. @piojo

Comment: @spark Are you sure you don't want to create a new object which is the combination of the first query and the new condition?

Comment: @piojo Right, that one is just really similar than the other one.

Nevertheless this question is missing important information:
* Used rustc version
* Relevant part of schema.rs
* Definitions of any type that is not coming from a crate mentioned in the question (`JsonRequest` for example)

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail information, I guessing you want to do condition query with diesel. For example, if your request contains condition named `company`, You can tried to append the filter like this way:

```
let mut query = interview::table.into_boxed::<diesel::pg::Pg>();
if let Some(query_company) = &request.company {
    query = query.filter(interview::company.like(format!("{}{}{}","%",query_company.as_str(),"%")));
}
```

then you can append any condition filter like this way.